# How to find the numbers between A and B that can be divided by C number?

Tags: math, flowgorithm

I want to find the numbers between A and B that can be diveded by C using flowgorithm or a math formula.

As of now I can only output the numbers between the two given numbers.

I want to get the results and be able to average them and sum them.

Edit: I am trying to learn maths for obvious reasons and trying to understand the points of it, where to use what and formulas. Even though I tried, I couldn't find an information about how to solve this problem of mine on the internet. So my point is, I don't anyone to write the code for me, I just want to learn how to write it and what is logic behind it as I litteraly have no other sources at the moment. Thanks, if you take your time and help me.

Comment: No, I don't want anybody to write me a piece of code. I am politely asking something that I cloudn't find in anywhere on the internet and been working on for sometime now. I also clearly stated that I want the average of the numbers and be able to sum them for which it is clear that an array is needed and in the program that I am using I can't find how to use it. I am not very clear about maths and trying to get help for using it, trying to learn as best as I can do. Sorry to bother you sir. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to write a formula for this problem that will work in all computer languages, since the languages differ in how they treat integer division. Some languages have the modulo operator and some do not. But here is a hint to get started.

You definitely want the first number that is greater than or equal to `A` that is divisible by `C`. I'll assume that `A`, `B`, and `C` are positive integers--if that is not the case, things get more complicated and depend more on the computer language. Then the formula is

```
firstdivisible = ceil(A / C) * C
```

where `ceil` is the "ceiling" function--rounding *up* to an integer. Most languages have this function. Note that you will need to test if this number is greater than `B`.

You also want the last number in your range that is divisible by `C`, which is

```
lastdivisible = floor(B / C) * C
```

where `floor` rounds *down* to an integer. Some languages use `int` rather than `floor`. Again, you will need to test if this number is less than `A`. Some languages have a modulo operator `%`--if so, you could also use

```
lastdivisible = B - (B % C)
```

Given those limits and the spacing `C` you should be able to create an array with all your desired numbers.

Comment: ... but of course you do not need to make an array of all those numbers in order to calculate their sum and average.

Comment: Hey, I managed to create the array but anyway, I am still in the phase of summing or averaging them. Any help would still be helpfull. Also, thank you Rory for your answer.